# I receive the error message "pwEntries is not defined" in my node.js mongodb project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm receiving this error message:

```
25|                    
26|                     `<div class="divTableRow">`
```

> > 27|                       `<% pwEntries.forEach(pwEntry => { %>`
> > 28|                         `<div class="divTableCell">`
> > 29|                             `<span class="cellContent" spellcheck="false" id="password-entry">`
> > 30|                               `<%= pwEntry.password %>`

pwEntries is not defined

and I can't fix it. I want my app to save the values of the three inputs of my form with the class name new-password to my mongodb database, in order to display them later in the table of the same ejs file.

Here are my files:

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const { requireAuth, checkUser } = require('./middleware/authMiddleware');

const app = express();

// middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// database connection
const dbURI = ...
mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(3000)
    console.log("app listening to port 3000");
    console.log("database connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));





// routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index.ejs'));
app.get('/manager', requireAuth, checkUser, (req, res) => res.render('man.ejs'));
app.use(authRoutes);
```

authController.js:

```
const User = require("../models/User");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const pw_entry = require("../models/pw_entry");

const handleErrors = (err) => {
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
    let errors = {email: "", password: ""};

    if (err.message === "Incorrect email") {
      errors.email = "Email is not registered";
    }

    if (err.message === "Incorrect password") {
      errors.password = "Password is incorrect ";
    }

    if (err.code === 11000) {
        errors.email = "Email is already registered";
        return errors;
    }

    if (err.message.includes("user validation failed")) {
        Object.values(err.errors).forEach(({properties}) => {
            errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
        });
    }

    return errors;
}

const maxAge = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60
const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({ id }, "keytodecodetokens", {
        expiresIn: maxAge
    });
}

module.exports.signup_get = (req, res) => {
    res.render("signup.ejs");
}

module.exports.login_get = (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs");
}

module.exports.signup_post = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
       const user = await User.create({ name, email, password});
       const token = createToken(user._id);
       res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000});
       res.status(201).json({ user: user._id });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        const errors = handleErrors(err);
        res.status(400).json({errors});
    }
}

module.exports.login_post = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.login(email, password);
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie("jwt", token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000});
    res.status(200).json({ user: user._id });
  } 
  catch (err) {
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }
}

module.exports.logout_get = (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("jwt", "", {maxAge: 1});
  res.redirect("/login")
}

module.exports.addPassword_post = async (req, res) => {
  const { password, website, email } = req.body;
  const userId = req.user._id;

  try {
    const pwEntry = await pw_entry.create({ password, website, email, user: userId });
    res.status(201).json({ pwEntry });
    console.log({ pwEntry });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }
}

module.exports.getPasswordEntries_get = async (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.user._id; 

  try {
    const pwEntries = await pw_entry.find({ user: userId });
    res.render("man.ejs", { user: req.user, pwEntries: pwEntries }); 
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
};
```

authRoutes.js:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const authController = require("../controllers/authController");
const router = Router();
const pw_entry = require("../models/pw_entry");
const { requireAuth } = require("../middleware/authMiddleware");

//signup
router.get("/signup", authController.signup_get);
router.post("/signup", authController.signup_post);

//login
router.get("/login", authController.login_get);
router.post("/login", authController.login_post);

//logout
router.get("/logout", authController.logout_get);

//manager
router.post("/addPasswordEntry", requireAuth, authController.addPassword_post);
router.get("/passwordEntries", requireAuth, authController.getPasswordEntries_get);


module.exports = router;
```

man.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/styles/man-style.css">
    <script src="../public/scripts/script2.js" defer></script>
    <script src="../public/scripts/matrix.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
  <canvas id="Matrix"></canvas>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="machine-background">
            <div class="display">
                <span class="welcome-user">Ready to manage your passwords, <%= user.name %> ...</span>
                <div class="divTable">
                    <div class="divTableRow" id="divHeaderRow">
                    <div class="divTableHeaderCell">Password</div>
                    <div class="divTableHeaderCell">Website</div>
                    <div class="divTableHeaderCell">Email</div>
                    </div>
                    <% pwEntries.forEach(pwEntry => { %>
                    <div class="divTableRow">
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <span class="cellContent" spellcheck="false" id="password-entry">
                              <%= pwEntry.password %>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <span class="cellContent" spellcheck="false" id="website-entry">
                              <%= pwEntry.website %>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divTableCell">
                            <span class="cellContent" spellcheck="false" id="email-entry">
                              <%= pwEntry.email %>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <% }); %>
                        <div class="edit-mode-display">
                            <span class="edit-mode">-- Edit Mode active --</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <footer>
                    <div class="page-navigation">
                        <a href="" class="nav-arrow"><</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav-button">1</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav-button">2</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav-button">3</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav-button">4</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav-button">5</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav-arrow">></a>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </div>
            <div class="control-section">
                <button data-modal-target="#modal" class="control-btn" id="control-btn-add">
                    <svg id="add-svg" fill="#000000" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 459.325 459.325" xml:space="preserve"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <g> <path d="M459.319,229.668c0,22.201-17.992,40.193-40.205,40.193H269.85v149.271c0,22.207-17.998,40.199-40.196,40.193 c-11.101,0-21.149-4.492-28.416-11.763c-7.276-7.281-11.774-17.324-11.769-28.419l-0.006-149.288H40.181 c-11.094,0-21.134-4.492-28.416-11.774c-7.264-7.264-11.759-17.312-11.759-28.413C0,207.471,17.992,189.475,40.202,189.475h149.267 V40.202C189.469,17.998,207.471,0,229.671,0c22.192,0.006,40.178,17.986,40.19,40.187v149.288h149.282 C441.339,189.487,459.308,207.471,459.319,229.668z"></path> </g> </g></svg>
                </button>
                <button onclick="window.location.href='/';" class="control-btn" id="control-btn-generate">
                    <svg id="gen-svg" fill="#000000" height="200px" width="200px" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 460 460" xml:space="preserve"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <g id="XMLID_241_"> <g> <path d="M369.635,0H90.365C73.595,0,60,13.595,60,30.365v399.27C60,446.405,73.595,460,90.365,460h279.27 c16.77,0,30.365-13.595,30.365-30.365V30.365C400,13.595,386.405,0,369.635,0z M108.204,343.61v-43.196 c0-3.451,2.797-6.248,6.248-6.248h43.196c3.451,0,6.248,2.797,6.248,6.248v43.196c0,3.451-2.797,6.248-6.248,6.248h-43.196 C111.001,349.858,108.204,347.06,108.204,343.61z M108.204,256.61v-43.196c0-3.451,2.797-6.248,6.248-6.248h43.196 c3.451,0,6.248,2.797,6.248,6.248v43.196c0,3.451-2.797,6.248-6.248,6.248h-43.196C111.001,262.858,108.204,260.06,108.204,256.61 z M308.891,421H151.109c-11.046,0-20-8.954-20-20c0-11.046,8.954-20,20-20h157.782c11.046,0,20,8.954,20,20 C328.891,412.046,319.937,421,308.891,421z M208.402,294.165h43.196c3.451,0,6.248,2.797,6.248,6.248v43.196 c0,3.451-2.797,6.248-6.248,6.248h-43.196c-3.451,0-6.248-2.797-6.248-6.248v-43.196 C202.154,296.963,204.951,294.165,208.402,294.165z M202.154,256.61v-43.196c0-3.451,2.797-6.248,6.248-6.248h43.196 c3.451,0,6.248,2.797,6.248,6.248v43.196c0,3.451-2.797,6.248-6.248,6.248h-43.196C204.951,262.858,202.154,260.06,202.154,256.61 z M345.548,349.858h-43.196c-3.451,0-6.248-2.797-6.248-6.248v-43.196c0-3.451,2.797-6.248,6.248-6.248h43.196 c3.451,0,6.248,2.797,6.248,6.248v43.196h0C351.796,347.061,348.999,349.858,345.548,349.858z M345.548,262.858h-43.196 c-3.451,0-6.248-2.797-6.248-6.248v-43.196c0-3.451,2.797-6.248,6.248-6.248h43.196c3.451,0,6.248,2.797,6.248,6.248v43.196h0 C351.796,260.061,348.999,262.858,345.548,262.858z M354,149.637c0,11.799-9.565,21.363-21.363,21.363H127.364 C115.565,171,106,161.435,106,149.637V62.363C106,50.565,115.565,41,127.364,41h205.273C344.435,41,354,50.565,354,62.363V149.637 z"></path> </g> </g> </g></svg>
                </button>
                <button class="control-btn" id="control-btn-edit">
                    <svg id="edit-svg" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 528.899 528.899" xml:space="preserve"><g id="SVGRepo_bgCarrier" stroke-width="0"></g><g id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></g><g id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"> <g> <path d="M328.883,89.125l107.59,107.589l-272.34,272.34L56.604,361.465L328.883,89.125z M518.113,63.177l-47.981-47.981 c-18.543-18.543-48.653-18.543-67.259,0l-45.961,45.961l107.59,107.59l53.611-53.611 C532.495,100.753,532.495,77.559,518.113,63.177z M0.3,512.69c-1.958,8.812,5.998,16.708,14.811,14.565l119.891-29.069 L27.473,390.597L0.3,512.69z"></path> </g> </g></svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="logout-section">
                <button onclick="window.location.href='/logout';" class="logout-btn">L O G O U T</button>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class="new-password-container">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <label class="new-password-header" for="new-password-container">N E W &nbsp; P A S S W O R D
          <span class="nails" id="left-top">.</span>
          <span class="nails" id="right-top">.</span>
          <span class="nails" id="right-bot">.</span>
          <span class="nails" id="left-bot">.</span>
        </label>
        <button data-close-button class="close-button">X</button>
      </div>
      <form action="/addPasswordEntry" method="POST" class="new-password">
        <input type="text" name="newpassword" id="new-password-input" class="new-input" spellcheck="false" placeholder="enter password ...">
        <input type="text" name="website" id="new-website-input" class="new-input" spellcheck="false" placeholder="enter website ...">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="new-email-input" class="new-input" spellcheck="false" placeholder="enter email ...">
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="addbutton">
      </form>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked the spelling, checked the imports of other files like the mongoose schema of pw_entry, checked the correct ejs implementing of code and checked the definition of pwEntries in my authController file and I can't help it. Maybe you can tell me whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Please remove your cluster connection credentials from the `dbURI` in your post and then change your password on your cluster once you do.

Comment: @flexbeatz share the exact and complete error you are getting.

Comment: 25|                    
    26|                     <div class="divTableRow">
 >> 27|                       <% pwEntries.forEach(pwEntry => { %>
    28|                         <div class="divTableCell">
    29|                             <span class="cellContent" spellcheck="false" id="password-entry">
    30|                               <%= pwEntry.password %>

pwEntries is not defined

Comment: the complete error message is not being displayed properly in my question so I wrote it here in the comments as well